# Problems with Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm doing some simple tasks to prepare myself for python on University I am going to attend but I ran into a problem. 
When I ran my code for the first time, the tkinter window appeared and the image was drawn, but when I ran it for the second time, the tkinter window did not appear :( 
This is the code:

```
import math, tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
n = int(input('enter n: '))
x0, y0, r = 150, 150, 100
xx, yy = x0+r, y0
uhol = 360/n
for i in range(n):
    rad = uhol/180*math.pi
    x = x0 + r * math.cos(rad)
    y = y0 + r * math.sin(rad)
    canvas.create_line(x, y, xx, yy)
    xx, yy = x, y
    uhol += 360/n
```

Few hours before that, I wrote this code and it's working everytime I run it:

```
import math, tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
x0, y0, r = 150, 150, 100
xx, yy = x0+r, y0
for uhol in range(10, 361, 10):
    rad = uhol/180*math.pi
    x = x0 + r * math.cos(rad)
    y = y0 + r * math.sin(rad)
    canvas.create_line(x, y, xx, yy)
    xx, yy = x, y
```

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the second 'first' should be 'second'.  There are two other problems.

You did not say *how* you ran this either time.  Exact details can be important.

You did not create and pass to Canvas an instance of tkinter.Tk.  Instead, you relied on the default root mechanism.  I consider this unreliable and a bad idea.  Among other things, you cannot call methods on the hidden root.

I loaded your code into an IDLE editor, changed lines 2 & 3 to

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
```

hit F5, and it ran.  I hit F5 again and it ran.  And again, and again.

To run from a command line or by double-clicking the file, you probably need to add this line at the end.

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I ran it in IDLE everytime. I did what you have suggested in IDLE(Python 3.5) and it didnt work BUT when I ran it in PyCharm it worked so thank you :)

Comment: I just retried with 3.5.2 on Win10 and it works, so there is something different about your system.